# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError - C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I send the information from the database without any problems. But I can not load the table in the page. However, when I make an alert to see what I have received, the information seems to have come as json, but it continues to give the wrong image in the picture. How I can fix it ?

[image: Image is here with error and alert.]

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Sil</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:friends">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text:id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:sales"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:price"></td>
                <td><input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.removeUser" value="X" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>Name</div> <input data-bind="value: Name" /> <br />
    <div>Sales </div> <input data-bind="value: Sales" /> <br />
    <div>Price </div> <input data-bind="value: Price" /> <br />

    <button data-bind="click:addUser">Ekle</button>
    <button data-bind="click:removeUserAll">Hepsini Sil</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        this.Name = ko.observable();
        this.Sales = ko.observable();
        this.Price = ko.observable();

        function functionViewModel() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                        var initialData = msg.d;
                    }
                });
            });
            var fn = {
                friends: ko.observableArray(initialData)
            };

            return fn;
        };

        ko.applyBindings(functionViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Backend Code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string GonderUrunler()
        {
            denemeDBEntities db = new denemeDBEntities();
            var result = from d in db.urunler.ToList()
                         select d;
            string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
            return output;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a callback with ajax.Because ajax work async
check [This](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) document.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

      function functionViewModel(callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "KnockoutGrid2.aspx/GonderUrunler",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                  callback({friends: ko.observableArray(msg.d)});
                }
            });
    };

    functionViewModel(function(response){
       ko.applyBindings(response.friends)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if 'friends' is really set and is an array? You use it in your foreach templating. It seams that Knockout cannot load the array...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:friends">
```

Comment: if I write like this foreach is working but this time I do not have data from the database.

var fn = {
                friends: ko.observableArray([{ "id": 1, "name": "Well-Travelled Kitten", "sales": "352", "price": "75.95" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Speedy Coyote", "sales": "89", "price": "190.00".... }])
            };

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a JSON-formatted string from the WebMethod, so in your JS code you need to deserialise that to an object so you can work with the data contained in it. To do that use `JSON.parse`:

```
success: function (msg) {
  var data = JSON.parse(msg);
  console.log(data[0].id);
  console.log(data[0].name);
}
```

A couple of things to note here. Firstly, `data` will be an array so if you need to retrieve all the information contained in it you'll need to use a loop. Secondly, always use `console.log` or `console.dir` when debugging. `alert()` will coerce data types, so it's not reliable at all.